# If statement inside TreeMap in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a `TreeMap<Long,ArrayList<String>>` that I need t print it in Struts2 jsp page. I have to add an If condition in such a way that If the content of `ArrayList<String>` contains certain character sequence I need to print it in one color and if does not have that character sequence I need to print it in different color.

In the below code, only else part is getting printed,

```
<s:set name="string1" value="check_Char" />

<s:iterator value="lgMap">
            <h3>
                <s:property value="key" />
            </h3>
            <table>
                <s:iterator value="value">
                    <s:if test="%{<s:property />.indexOf(#string1)) == -1}">
                        <tr>
                            <td><font color="green"><s:property /></font>   </td>
                        </tr>
                    </s:if>
                    <s:else>
                        <tr>
                            <td><font color="red"><s:property /></font></td>
                        </tr>
                    </s:else>
                </s:iterator>
            </table>
        </s:iterator>
```

There is problem with the if statement i believe. Can one suggest how to reach the if part?

Comment: Is your `getCheck_Char()` method being called?

Comment: Yeah. I am pretty sure it is getting called. I ran the program in debug mode. I could see check_Char holds the String which I passed.

Comment: Could you show what `getCheck_Char()` method returns and what is inside your ArrayList?

Comment: `private String check_Char = "-EDT|INFO|WP/WLID";`


`public String getCheck_Char() {return check_Char; }`

ArrayList has list of strings.

Comment: Maybe all strings inside ArrayList contains this `-EDT|INFO|WP/WLID` substring?

Comment: No. I checked that lot of times. But still not getting it. Will update if I get something.

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest Struts Tags.

Change this

```
<s:if test="%{<s:property />.indexOf(#string1)) == -1}">
```

to this

```
<s:if test="%{top.indexOf(#string1) == -1}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and it is not working. still it is taking me to the else part only.

Comment: @sbala_20: There was a typo -> `)`.

Comment: Same even after changing that. Here is the code,


  '<s:set name="string1" value="check_Char" />
  checking String : <s:property value="string1" />


  <s:iterator value="logMap">
    <s:property value="key" />
   <table>
    <s:iterator value="value">
     <s:if test="%{top.indexOf(#string1) == -1}">
      <tr>
       <td><font color="green"><s:property /></font></td>
      </tr>
     </s:if>

     <s:else>
      <tr>
       <td><font color="red"><s:property /></font></td>
      </tr>
     </s:else>
    </s:iterator>
   </table>
  </s:iterator>'